# Prefer personal license over network license

Tags: licensing

I have activated Mathematica with a personal license and a network license. The idea for this is that I want to be able to use as many kernels as possible from my machine if I need them.
My goal is that if I launch Mathematica it should use the personal license. Further instances of Mathematica should use one of the network licenses.

If I am not connected to the internet I can start Mathematica (twice) and it uses my personal license without any problems. As I am not connected to the internet I obviously can not use the network licenses.

However, if I am connected to the internet Mathematica first uses all the network licenses, before it accesses my personal license.
This is annoying because it basically wastes the personal license and I am blocking one network license for no reason.

How can I tell Mathematica to use my personal license before falling back to the network licenses? If this is not possible how can I deactivate the network license?

Comment: Licensing questions should be directed to Wolfram Support.

Comment: @MarcoB Can you reopen the question such that I can post the answer I received from Wolfram support?

Comment: I voted to reopen. You may also raise a flag ("in need of moderator attention") and explain the situation to a moderator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This answer is based on a helpful mail from Wolfram support.

Mathematica stores the License information in a text file called `mathpass`.
In this file, each line corresponds to one licensing possibility, which Mathematica reads line by line. It tries to use the license information in the first row and if this fails (because e.g. the activation key is wrong or the license server cannot be contacted) the next row is tried.

This means, to prefer `license1` over `license2` the entry of `license1` has to appear above `license2` in the `mathpass` file.

[Here is the corresponding documentation by Wolfram support.](https://support.wolfram.com/112)

---

The `mathpass` file can be located at a [variety of places](https://support.wolfram.com/25655).

Therefore, one should modify the `mathpass` file at all of these locations.